# Only single space after each character or word. Space is not allowed at firs or last

Tags: regex

I have written below RegEx:

```
^\w+( \w+)*$
```

I want to limit whole string length to minimum 3 and maximum 30.

Comment: And what did you try to enforce the limits? Any limiting quantifiers?

Comment: Like whole length should be between {3,30} . but when i am adding this condition it is getting wrong.

Comment: Please give example of your input and output. Besides that `\w` also include `_` character. Do you wish that to be in string too ?

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC3jH6/1) with `^\w+( \w+){2,29}$`.

Comment: e.g:  1 ]abc 123 xyz    
         2]abc
No two or more spaces should be  between one world and another.
And no spaces at start or at the end.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew : It is not allowing single word string without spaces at first or at last.

Comment: Ok, you want to only allow 3 to 30 ASCII letters inside each non-whitespace chunk? Note that your example contains `1` word and it is 1-char long. What is the minimum and what is the maximum string examples?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You seem to restrict the number of words (non-whitespace chunks) in a string, but you say my regex is not working for you because it does not allow 1 single word string without spaces. It should not match it acc. to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at start to check for the total length.

```
^(?=.{3,30}$)\w+( \w+)*$
```

`^(?=.{3,30}$)` at start looks ahead, if there's 3 to 30 of any character until `$` the end. This will check, if the total length is between 3 and 30 characters. Use with `s` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) if needed.

[Check demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uN0iK8/1)

Comment: Yes, it only checks the character length of the whole string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right, that's how I understand the question :)